# Get correct data desire when override function in java

Tags: java, overriding

I have piece code, when I call method **getData()**, I need to receive data is a list have data, but, I always receive data equal null. The reason I get such results because the thread will run functions **List comments = new ArrayList<>();** -> **MutableLiveData<List> list = new MutableLiveData<>();** ->  **return list;** ->  **comments.add(comment);**. is there any way i can resolve this problem.

```
List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
public MutableLiveData<List<Comment>> getData(BaiHat song){
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    MutableLiveData<List<Comment>> list = new MutableLiveData<>();
    db.collection(KEY_COLLECTION_COMMENT)
            .whereEqualTo(KEY_SONG,song.getIdBaiHat())
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                    if(error !=null){
                        return;
                    }
                    if(value!=null){
                        for(DocumentChange documentChange: value.getDocumentChanges()){
                            if(documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                                Comment comment = new Comment();
                                comment.setComment(documentChange.getDocument().getString(KEY_COMMENT));
                                comment.setEmail(documentChange.getDocument().getString(KEY_EMAIL));
                                comments.add(comment);
                            }
                        }
                        list.postValue(comments);
                    }
                }
            });

    return list;
}
```

Comment: Looking at your code I don't see any way that `getData` can return `null`.

Comment: set break points and start debugging.

Comment: One diff suggestion, inside if(error !=null){}, you may want to print the error, cause.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is mixing synchronous and asynchronous code.

You need to provide a a mechanism to synchronize between them. Here is example using CountDownLatch.

```
List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

public MutableLiveData<List<Comment>> getData(BaiHat song) {
    CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
    MutableLiveData<List<Comment>> list = new MutableLiveData<>();
    db.collection(KEY_COLLECTION_COMMENT)
            .whereEqualTo(KEY_SONG, song.getIdBaiHat())
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        doneSignal.countDown();
                        return;
                    }
                    if (value != null) {
                        for (DocumentChange documentChange : value.getDocumentChanges()) {
                            if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                                Comment comment = new Comment();
                                comment.setComment(documentChange.getDocument().getString(KEY_COMMENT));
                                comment.setEmail(documentChange.getDocument().getString(KEY_EMAIL));
                                comments.add(comment);
                            }
                        }
                        list.postValue(comments);
                    }
                    doneSignal.countDown();
                }
            });
    doneSignal.await(); // wait for all to finish
    return list;
}
```